# Help I'm puzzled

Tags: jigsaw-puzzle

My dad was fixing the driveway and later asked me to see if I could get some help with this[image: these are the pieces]
[image: this is the space the pieces needs to be put back here]

I'd appreciate your help
MIKEY G

Comment: This looks like an off-topic question...until you scroll down a bit.

Comment: +1 for being bold enough to fix the ditch with different colored bricks

Comment: Can we flip the pieces and also should the lines on the pieces 'match' with the tiles, once arranged properly ?

Comment: Hmm, the pieces might fit together to outline a hole that matches, rather than fills, the hole in the driveway . . . (I don't have the means to try it.)

Comment: Are the pieces all right-side-up? Are all the bricks the same size? Are we "making" the hole or filling the hole?

Comment: If these pieces are not originally from this driveway it won't fit.. Instead pour concrete in and chisel/draw the lines..

Answer (score 6):

Just fill the rest in with sand or something.
I used the small piece on the brick at the top of the image to fill in the remaining triangle at the bottom.

And maybe a little bit of your toe.

> [image: bricks]